# Nokogiri parsing through XML fails

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

The code:

```
  response = Nokogiri::XML(open('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3+%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+44%D0%A2'), nil, Encoding::UTF_8.to_s)

  lowerCorner = response.xpath("//lowerCorner")
```

XML document I parse is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ymaps xmlns="http://maps.yandex.ru/ymaps/1.x" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="     http://maps.yandex.ru/business/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/business/1.x/business.xsd     http://maps.yandex.ru/geocoder/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/geocoder/1.x/geocoder.xsd     http://maps.yandex.ru/psearch/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/psearch/1.x/psearch.xsd     http://maps.yandex.ru/search/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/search/1.x/search.xsd     http://maps.yandex.ru/web/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/web/1.x/web.xsd     http://maps.yandex.ru/search/internal/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/search/internal/1.x/internal.xsd">
  <GeoObjectCollection>
    <metaDataProperty xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
      <GeocoderResponseMetaData xmlns="http://maps.yandex.ru/geocoder/1.x">
        <request>Санкт-Петербург Свердловская набережная 44Т</request>
        <found>1</found>
        <results>10</results>
      </GeocoderResponseMetaData>
    </metaDataProperty>
    <featureMember xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
      <GeoObject xmlns="http://maps.yandex.ru/ymaps/1.x" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" gml:id="1">
        <metaDataProperty xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
          <GeocoderMetaData xmlns="http://maps.yandex.ru/geocoder/1.x">
            <kind>house</kind>
            <text>Россия, Санкт-Петербург, Свердловская набережная, 44Т</text>
            <precision>exact</precision>
          </GeocoderMetaData>
        </metaDataProperty>
          <Envelope>
            <lowerCorner>30.397902 59.959183</lowerCorner>
            <upperCorner>30.406113 59.9633</upperCorner>
          </Envelope>
        </boundedBy>
        <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
          <pos>30.402008 59.961242</pos>
        </Point>
      </GeoObject>
    </featureMember>
  </GeoObjectCollection>
</ymaps>
```

I'd like to get lowerCorner, but nothing from official and others sources does work:

```
response.xpath('//lowerCorner')
response.search('//lowerCorner')
response.xpath('xmlns:lowerCorner')
response.xpath('xmlns:lowerCorner', ns).text
response.css('lowerCorner')
```

The only result is: []

So how to parse lowerCorner's content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the namespaces (or using them in your path) should help.
Try this:

```
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"
response = Nokogiri::XML(open('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3+%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+44%D0%A2'), nil, Encoding::UTF_8.to_s)
response.remove_namespaces! # <<<<<<<
lower_corner = response.xpath("/ymaps/GeoObjectCollection/featureMember/GeoObject/boundedBy/Envelope/lowerCorner").first
p lower_corner.text #> "30.397902 59.959183"
```